# SSIS - How to load/import csv files from multiple folder location

Tags: csv, ssis

Can someone help me with this scenario.

**Step 1:** Need to look for .csv files from different folder locations

**Folder1/File 1:**

\xxxxx\yyyyy\zzzzz\Folder1\file1

id,name,dob,city,state,country

aaa,kevin,01/10/1985,Kansas,Missouri,USA

bbb,Jack,10/05/1980,Detroit,Michigan,USA

**Folder 2 - File 2**

\xxxxx\yyyyy\zzzzz\Folder2\file2

id,name,hobby,city

aaa,kevin,Football,Kansas

ccc,Bob,baseball,San Jose

**Folder 3 - File 3**

\xxxxx\yyyyy\zzzzz\Folder3\file3

id,name,city,Employer

aaa,kevin,Kansas,Empl1

ddd,Jake,Dallas,Empl2

**Step 2:** Get Common column names/values from each csv files (example: id, name, city)

**Step 3:** Get distinct values and Combine them into a single csv file

**Step 4:** Insert the distinct values (from step 3) into a table in SQL Server

**Step 5:** Export the new Csv file (from step 3) to a new location

**Final : Output CSV**

id,name,city

aaa,kevin,Kansas

bbb,Jack,Detroit

ccc,Bob,San Jose

ddd,Jake,Dallas

Comment: Given your sample folder locations, could it be that we need to also look at `c:\temp\folder4` or can we assume that the sub folders are all parented to a common location (Desktop)?

Comment: Also, as a design/implementation consideration, don't use paths based on Users folders. This introduces challenges at implementation time with permissions (that are often masked by the SSIS engine) especially when run by an account that is not the creator account.

Comment: Sub folders are all parented to "Desktop"

Comment: "Also, as a design/implementation consideration, don't use paths based on Users folders. This introduces challenges at implementation time with permissions (that are often masked by the SSIS engine) especially when run by an account that is not the creator account." To your question, i have just provided the folder location as just examples.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the edits/updates. Can you help me understand what the CSV format is going to be? Is it consistent across all files we find: is it truly comma delimited or might we find other delimiters? Do they all have header rows? Are there quote delimited columns in the mix? Are the quote delimited columns using the same delimiter? Are the files using the same row delimiter (typically carriage return or carriage return and line feed)?

Comment: Step 3 question - Folder1\file1.csv has `ID|Name|City` with a data row like `1|Gopal|New York` Folder2\file2.csv has `1|Bill|New York` What happens there - IDs match but values differ? Do you expect to insert 2 rows? If not, what rules for survivorship exist?

Comment: I edited my question again. Hope this helps!.